# Turn electricity into light and converse

Tags: electricity

can i just turn electricity into light and back¿?

light is a wave so i can send light from point to point

the idea would be applied to have wireless electricity in the world, turning electricity into light

at the point A and then sending the light wirelessly from point A to B and turn back light into

electricity at the point B so we don't need cables anymore

Comment: Fiber optics...

Comment: Wireless power transmission is very inefficient which is why it is not used commercially. You only really find it in experimental research such as the UAV that is powered by aiming a powerful laser at the onboard solar cell. The solar cell is usually 15% efficient at best and the laser 1% efficient so the total overall efficiency is 0.15% efficient. That's under lab conditions. Out in the real world it can be considerably less.

Comment: @DKNguyen that should be an answer

Comment: For the first, use an electric bulb. For the second, use a solar cell.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless power transmission is very inefficient which is why it is not used commercially. You only really find it in experimental research such as the UAV that is powered by aiming a powerful laser at the onboard solar cell. The solar cell is usually 15% efficient at best and the laser 1% efficient so the total overall efficiency is 0.15% efficient. That's under lab conditions. Out in the real world it can be considerably less.

Also, such powerful lasers cause eye damage from any angle just from scattering off air molecules.